# SQL if-else statement to check for a specific character

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am a complete novice when it comes to SQL so I'm hoping someone can help me out, what I need to do is create an if-else statement that checks to see if a specific character exists ('/') if it does then ignore the text after this until a white space is found.

When the white space is found only return the 5th and 6th characters. If no ('/) is found then simply return the 5th and 6th characters.

My code what I have so far is below and I know this could be a lot cleaner but I am just now learning SQL so my apologies.

```
select top 10000
full_message,

SUBSTRING (full_message,CHARINDEX(':52A:', full_message) + 5,  CHARINDEX(':5', full_message, (CHARINDEX(':52A:', full_message)+1)) -  CHARINDEX(':52A:', full_message) - 5) as [CountryCode]

-- create if-else statement to see if the first character is a '/' if it is from the white space take the 5th & 6th characters.

-- else take the 5th & 6th characters  

from [dbo].[tbl_Test] where CHARINDEX(':52A:', full_message) > 0
```

My CountryCode column returns values like:-

1. Value returned with a ('/RandomString')

   /04457120 GZQRUSAXXX
2. Value returned without a ('/RandomString')

   LTDXGB7PXXX

So ideally the CountryCode column will return

1. Value returned with a ('/RandomString') then removed

   US
2. Value returned without ('/RandomString')

   GB

I hope this question makes sense and if you need me to better clarify something then please do I am using Microsoft SQL.

Kind regards,

Ryan

Comment: what is '/' is found but no space after this ?

Comment: @GuidoG there is always a space after in the message I am looking in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this.

It's shorter and also includes a check for `/` and `space` afterwards.

```
DECLARE @full_message varchar(100) = '/04457120 GZQRUSAXXX'

SELECT
(CASE WHEN CHARINDEX('/', @full_message) > 0 AND CHARINDEX(' ', @full_message, CHARINDEX('/', @full_message)) > 0
THEN SUBSTRING(@full_message, CHARINDEX(' ', @full_message, CHARINDEX('/', @full_message))+5, 2)
ELSE SUBSTRING(@full_message, 5, 2)
END) AS Countrycode
```

NOTE: There's no check for length in this query.

Comment: I agree this version is better

Comment: Thanks for your answer Mat really appreciate it, I'm on the right path now.

Answer (score 2):

to get US from '/04457120 GZQRUSAXXX' you need char 5 and 6
to get GB from 'LTDXGB7PXXX' you need char 5 and 6

a query to do this could by like this :

```
declare @full_message varchar(100) = '/04457120 GZQRUSAXXX' --  'LTDXGB7PXXX' 

select @full_message,
       case when charindex('/', @full_message) > 0 then
              substring(
              substring( substring(@full_message, charindex('/', @full_message) + 1, len(@full_message)),
                         charindex(' ', substring(@full_message, charindex('/', @full_message) + 1, len(@full_message))) + 1,
                         len(substring(@full_message, charindex('/', @full_message) + 1, len(@full_message)))
                       ), 5, 2)

            else 
              substring(@full_message, 5, 2)
       end
```

Please note this will only work if there is always a space after a '/'
Also there is no check for length in this query, if there are no 7 characters after the space it will also go wrong

Comment: When I was editing the codes I added an extra character in front of the country code, every message has the country code at the 5th and 6th index, I am pulling full_message from another database, thanks for the reply.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Guido I do appreciate it.

Comment: This is the beauty of this site, you have more than one solution to choose from. I agree that the other solution is easier to use